# How to add in nutch1.17 new urls in seed file will nutch fetch old urls and new urls?

Tags: nutch

May I know how to work in nutch if I am getting new urls daily to crawl new urls and how to store in crawldb.I am new to nutch please tell me the approach.

Answer (score 2):

New URLs can be added to Nutch's CrawlDb at any time using the [inject](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=122916815) command. The newly added URLs are then fetched and processed in the next generate-fetch-update cycle.